# NFET driving LED strip flickering when cold

Tags: mosfet, pwm

I am driving a NFET (AUIRLR2905Z) directly from the GPIO pin of ESP32, so it is driven with 3.3 V at a PWM frequency of 1 kHz. The NFET is driving a led strip which consumes around 5 A at 12 V, the length of the led strip is around 5 meters.

When the PCB (and so NFET) is cold the LED strip flickers when turned on and slowly stops flickering after a minute or two. I guess that is the NFET ringing. But if the PCB is warm (meaning it was operating for a few minutes and I quickly turn the LED strip on and off completely), the flickering does not occur on NFET startup. On NFET shutdown there is no flickering.

I would also like to point out, that at smaller loads (1-2 A), meaning a shorter LED strip, the flickering does not occur.

Datasheets:
MCU: ESP32 WROOM (https://empa.com/empaiot/esp-wroom-32d_esp32-wroom-32u_datasheet_en.pdf)

NFET: AUIRLR2905Z (https://4donline.ihs.com/images/VipMasterIC/IC/IRSD/IRSDS11213/IRSDS11213-1.pdf?hkey=6D3A4C79FDBF58556ACFDE234799DDF0)

MCU PS: HLK-PM03 (https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf-file/1399824/Hi-Link/HLK-PM03/1)

LED PS: MEANWELL SP-320-12 (https://us.rs-online.com/m/d/2156faf9b8b87f2189b791f4791cd42b.pdf)

LED STRIP: 12V 5630 60LED/m 12W/m

I understand I should use a gate driver, but I would like to understand the phenomenon. Thank you.

Comment: What's the power supply for the LEDs? When you pre-load it with a shortish LED string, does it start free of "flicker"? When you then add the N-FET controlled strip (or an input signal): flicker or no flicker? Does the transistor get hot to the touch?

Comment: The 12V power supply of the LEDS is different from the 3.3V power supply of the MCU (ESP32), but they are on the same common ground, both are separately powered from AC. The 12V power supply powers the LEDS (short and long strip) only without any flickering.

When LEDs are N-FET controlled, the short strip does not flicker, while the longer strip is flickering.

The N-FET gets warm by touch. I added a heatsink and the temperature is warm, but not extremely hot.

Comment: Have you thought it might be a cold LED strip that is causing the flicker? Please link all relevant data sheets.

Comment: It tried cutting the long LED strip into smaller parts and the flickering disappears. When soldered back together into a long led strip, the flickering is back.

Comment: @AnzeJarni I don't know if you have seen my answer, but the symptoms of your problem seem to be it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that your MOSFET gate threshold voltage is high, and it is well known that it rises at lower temperatures. 
The reason it flickers is because it is barely turning on and it presents a high(er) resistance because it needs a higher gate-source voltage until it warms up (plus some dynamic exchanges between gate and drain voltages and capacitances). 
Try it outside of the circuit and see at which gate-source voltage does it turn on. 
The [datasheet](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Infineon%20PDFs/AUIRLR2905Z.pdf) specifies the threshold voltage as:

---

> VGS(th) Gate Threshold Voltage Min: 1.0V, Max: 3.0V, VDS = VGS, ID = 250µA

---

As you can see, not only can its threshold voltage be as high as 3V, but it is also specified at the very low current of 250uA, which explains your shorter LED strip working fine at its much lower current, but the longer strip flickering with its much higher current which combined with the MOSFET's high R<sub>DS(on)</sub> (MOSFET channel resistance while turned on) makes the LEDs light up at the moment of turning on but quickly turning down as the MOSFET resistance presents a higher voltage drop at the higher current. 
A lower temperature will increase this threshold voltage, and a higher temperature will decrease it. 
I'm not sure, but I think this range of voltages is specified for high and low temperatures, still checking that.

One way you can solve your problem is by getting another MOSFET and ensuring (by testing) that it turns on at a lower G-S voltage. 
Another way is to add simple transistor circuit to "translate" your 3.3V logic to the 12V LED supply range which would definitely turn the MOSFET on at any temperature.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJabbD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In this case, you will have to invert the PWM logic at your ESP32 output because the NPN transistor will invert the phase and turn the wider positive PWM pulses into wider 0V pulses (shorter positive pulses) OR you could just add one more NPN transistor and a resistor, like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCRg9R.png)</sup>

Another solution is to buy a MOSFET whose threshold voltage is below 3V, i.e. no more than 2.7V, for example. There are quite a few models available with the upper threshold voltage below 2.7V.

Comment: Hi Edin, thank you for your answer. But I am curious, wouldn't it then flicker on the short and long strip just the same, if the NFET isn't supplied with a voltage high enough? It seems somehow to be load related...

Comment: @AnzeJarni No, because you are operating right around its turn on threshold voltage, and the MOSFET in that case doesn't fully turn on, i.e. it doesn't operate as a switch, but it starts conducting while having a much higher channel resistance and it acts like a resistor instead of a switch. The higher current of the longer LED strip will then cause a larger voltage drop across the MOSFET channel.

Comment: Thanks EDIN, I will certainly try to provide the NFET with a higher PWM voltage through another transistor or a function generator capable of higher voltages and disclose the results here.

Comment: @AnzeJarni You're welcome. You should also try another MOSFET of the same model OR, even better, buy a MOSFET whose maximum threshold voltage is less than 3V (2.5V for example). Feel free to look for one and ask me here (provide its model number) if it's a good choice.

Comment: Edin, confirmed. Ramping the voltage from 3.3V to 3.6V (which is still congestible to MCU) produces zero flickering on the LED strip, so I can confirm the problem was with the NFET not turning completely on due to inadequate voltage. Thank you so much.

Comment: @AnzeJarni You're welcome. That's another suggestion I forgot, to slightly raise the MCU supply voltage. Can't think of everything. You had that "eureka" or genius moment yourself. I just helped you get there. :D